# Dynamic programming (rod cutting) using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

So, I'm trying to make a simple implementation of a dynamic programming problem in java work. The method is the cut-rod method of Algorithms, third edition (by Rivest et al) chapter 15 here is my code -

```
public static double cutRod(double[] p, int n){
    if(n==0)return 0;
    double q = -1000;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        q = Math.max( q, p[i]+cutRod(p,n-i));
    }
    return q;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    double[] p = {1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20,24,30};
    double val = cutRod(p,10);
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

When I try and run this, I get a stack overflow error. Even when I try and debug it (I'm using netbeans), it pauses a while on the first recursive call and then gives me a stack overflow error. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the recursive method or use "Step into" instead of "Step over" to see what is really happening.

Comment: This isn't a dynamic program - for that you need to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) previously calculated values.

Comment: Yeah, I know there is a memoized version as well. I want to implement the naive recursive version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let cutRoad(n) be the required (best possible price) value for a rod of lenght n. cutRod(n) can be written as following.

```
cutRod(n) = max(price[i] + cutRod(n-i-1)) for all i in {0, 1 .. n-1}.
```

So it shoud be `n-i-1` not `n-i`.

```
            q = Math.max( q, p[i]+cutRod(p,n-i-1));
```

Please refer [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/)

Answer (score 2):

Just to point you in the right direction, consider your for loop. With i=0, every single call will just pass the same n into cutRod and the recursion will then never terminate.

Answer (score 2):

You call the recursion with exactly the same value of `n` in the first iteration of your loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    q = Math.max( q, p[i]+cutRod(p,n-i));
}
```

When `i=0` then you call `cutRod(p,n-0)` which is the same call again. This causes an infinite loop.

If you change your loop to:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    q = Math.max( q, p[i]+cutRod(p,n-i));
}
```

Then the recursion will terminate as the first value of `i` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow occures because your loop starts from 0:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    q = Math.max( q, p[i]+cutRod(p,n-i));
}
```

`n-i` when `i == 0` is `n`, so you don't reduce the range of the recursion and going 'closer' to the base, which causes StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        q = Math.max( q, p[i]+cutRod(p,n-i));
```

See what happens when `i = 0`,  `cutRod(p, n) calls cutRod(p, n-0)` = infinite loop

And with an infinite loop, the stack is bound to overflow because it has a finite size thats why you eventually get StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

package com.implement.algorithms;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class RodCut {

```
private static final int [] PRICE = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};
private static  int [] MAX_PRICE = new int[PRICE.length];

private static int maxPrice(int n){
    if(n == 1 ){
        return PRICE[0];
    }
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    int currentVal = 0;
    int maxVal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n - 1 ; i++ ){
        if(MAX_PRICE[n  - 1 - i] == -1){
            MAX_PRICE[n - 1 - i] = maxPrice(n-i-1);
        }
        currentVal = PRICE[i] + MAX_PRICE[n - i -1];

        if(currentVal > maxVal){
            maxVal = currentVal;
        }
    }
    return maxVal;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(PRICE));
    Arrays.fill(MAX_PRICE, -1);
    System.out.println(maxPrice(10));
}
```

}

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Please consider add an explanation instead just paste code. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

import static java.lang.Math.max;

public class cutrod{

```
private static int q;
private static int[] p = {0,1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20,24,30};
private static int[] r = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

public static int cutrod_aux(int[] p, int n, int[] r){

 if (r[n]>=0){return r[n];}
 if (n==0)   return q=0;
 for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++){
     q = max(q,p[i]+cutrod_aux(p,n-i,r));
         }
r[n]=q;
return q;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   cutrod_aux(p, 10, r);   
}
```

}